# Using node packages in browser with browserify - Uncaught ReferenceError: fileType is not defined

Tags: javascript, npm, file-type

I am trying to use the [file-type npm package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type) in the browser.

So far I have not been able to get the example code to execute as it throws the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: fileType is not defined

(Example code as specified here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type)

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'unicorn.png');
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = () => {
    fileType(new Uint8Array(this.response));
    //=> {ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png'}
};

xhr.send();
```

So far I have tried to include the file-type package in my index.html in a script tag however this did not work. A quick google revealed to me I should be using browserify in order to use npm packages in the browser, from here I:

I created a file called deps.js and added the file-type package like so

```
const fileType = require("file-type");
```

I then created a bundle from deps.js by running:

```
browserify deps.js -o bundle.js
```

I then added bundle.js to index.html like so:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

For reference here is code from: index.html, main.js and deps.js:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//main.js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'iris.webp');
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = () => {
    fileType(new Uint8Array(this.response));
    //=> {ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png'}
};

xhr.send();


//deps.js
const fileType = require("file-type");
```

If working correctly I would expect fileType to return an object that looks like:

```
{
  ext: 'webp',
  mime: 'image/webp'
}
```

If anybody could tell me where I am going wrong it would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the example on the front page of [browserify](http://browserify.org/) You still need to make the fileType object.

From what you've posted, `deps.js` makes a fileType object, but when you run it from the browser `deps.js` gets skipped.

To use `browserify` as they intentyou should put the line `const fileType = require("file-type");` at the top of `main.js` and run `browserify` against `main.js`

Alternatively include `deps.js` like so:

```html
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="deps.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```